# How to make this drawer higher?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I trivially tried to stretch the image vertically, it worked a little but since I need to make the drawer x2.5 times high it becomes conical while the little knob becomes oval. I also need to remove the knob shadow but this would be a totally different topic.

[image]

**edit**: I created a new question for phase 2 of my work, if you can help with it, you can find it here: [How to add a tag with right perspective on this drawer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/how-to-add-a-tag-with-right-perspective-on-this-drawer) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1) Duplicate the drawer layer and move it up. Turn the opacity down for the moved up drawer layer.

2) Still with that top layer selected, go to edit -> Transform -> Warp or Distort. Distort the top layer so it continues the drawer lines.

[image: distort drawer]

3) Use an opacity mask on the top layer to hide the bottom of it.

[image: stacked drawer output]

4) Use the clone stamp tool and healing brush to change the pattern of the wood.

Comment: wow! many thanks for the steps 1~4 however doing so the drawer is on proportionally deeper than its initial version.