# How to add a tag with right perspective on this drawer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

This question is a follow-up of: [How to make this drawer higher?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98752/how-to-make-this-drawer-higher)

I came to this result, now I need to add a little tag on the drawer but I don't know how to make it right with the drawer perspective. The tag should include a few letters and the text must also be in perspective.

Finally I would "whitening" the drawer making it more polished but doubt it is possible since this is derived from a photo and not a native illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the polygonal lasso tool, selecth with it the front panel, make a new layer, paint the selection.

[image]

Then goto Edit > Transform > select > Free transform or scale and drag the painted area smaller. Hold shift to keep the proportions. Move the new tag to the wanted place:

[image]

Now it's possible add some thickness by painting a darker and a lighter stripe around the tag. Use the polygonal lasso tool and paint the selections. You can also add some text. You can drag the text to fit to the tag by distorting it Edit > Transform > Distort:

[image]

Do not expect anything small to be readable in this low resolution. I think that you do much better by drawing your box in Illustrator or inkscape. It's trivial, if you use a photo as a reference.

This is an example from Illustrator (random colors, random dimensions, drawn from scratch, without an underlying reference.)

[image]

You can use the creation as vector or you can rasterize it to any pixel dimensions without losing the sharpness.

Comment: wow amazing! How did you design a drawer from scratch so quick??

Comment: @S.Redrum I drawed its vertical parts as seen from the top. Illustrator has 3D Extrude as an effect. It allows free selection of the height, colors, lightning viewing direction and perspective. The tag was made as in the Photoshop version. The back wall was edited to lower height manually and the bottom was colored manually. This all is less than 15 min job for a moderately experienced Illustrator user.  Virtuoso users need maybe only 5 min.

Comment: Many thanks for clarifications! I'll lookup this Virtuoso ;)